# osmdroid map tiles showing blank

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I am new to osmdroid and trying to show maps in android, it is not showing map only showing tiles in blank, not showing zoom control also.

my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MapView m_mapView; 
private int MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM = 16; 
private double MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE =  33.6667; 
// Default map Longitude: 
private double MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE = 73.1667;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    m_mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview); 
   // m_mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM); 
    m_mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    m_mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
    m_mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true); 
    m_mapView.setClickable(true); 
    m_mapView.setUseDataConnection(true); 
    m_mapView.getController().setZoom(16); 
   m_mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(33.6667, 73.1667)); 
}
```

i have added this in AndroidManifest,xml also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />   
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add this to your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```